# npm generates an EISDIR error when using the --prefix flag on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I'm using npm 3.10.10 on a Windows machine, and I'm trying to run `npm install` from a directory one level up from the directory that contains my `package.json` directory:

```
userfrosting/
    build/
        package.json
```

I'm using the [`prefix` configuration option](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix), which is supposed to allow me to do this.  From within the `userfrosting/` directory:

```
npm install --prefix "build/" -ddd
```

This generates the following error:

```
npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

If I run `npm install` directly within `build/`, it works perfectly fine.  I need to be able to run it from this parent directory, because it is part of a larger build tool.

This problem only occurs in a Windows environment - I have run it on *nix systems
without this issue.

My `package.json` passes validation as per http://package-json-validator.com/.

The full verbose output is as follows:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--prefix',
npm verb cli   'build/node_modules',
npm verb cli   '-ddd' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.0
npm sill loadCurrentTree Starting
npm sill install loadCurrentTree
npm sill install readGlobalPackageData
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData .
npm sill fetchOtherPackageData .
npm sill cache add args [ '.', null ]
npm verb cache add spec .
npm sill cache add parsed spec Result {
npm sill cache add   raw: '.',
npm sill cache add   scope: null,
npm sill cache add   escapedName: null,
npm sill cache add   name: null,
npm sill cache add   rawSpec: '.',
npm sill cache add   spec: 'D:\\dev\\userfrosting',
npm sill cache add   type: 'local' }
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install D:\dev\userfrosting
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native)
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData  error for . { Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native) errno: -4068, code: 'EISDIR', syscall: 'read' }
npm sill rollbackFailedOptional Starting
npm sill rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
npm sill runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
npm sill install printInstalled
npm verb stack Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm verb stack     at Error (native)
npm verb cwd D:\dev\userfrosting
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--prefix" "build/node_modules" "-ddd"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.
npm verb exit [ -4068, true ]

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\dev\userfrosting\npm-debug.log
```